# When and how is the code for library functions added in c?

Tags: c

When we include the header files in C , we actually add the declaration of the functions such as the printf , scanf etc. But how does the code for the function ( the function declaration ) get added to the program ?

Comment: The header files are added and you are just calling the function from the file.

Comment: This is a fair read on creating/using shared libraries: [**Yolinux.com Tutorial
Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries**](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's done by the process of *linking*. Individually compiled translation units have a way of referring to dependent names symbolically, so your code would only say "call a function with name 'printf'", and it is the job of the linking procedure to look up those symbols in one of the provided object or library files.

The standard library is usually linked against your code implicitly, so you may not be aware of the fact that you are linking your code with pre-existing library code. You would definitely be aware of this if you used your own libraries.

Note that there is no standard for linking, so you cannot generally compile one file with one compiler and another file with a different compiler and then link them together. The problem is not just to agree on how *names* are represented, but also on how to generate code for function calls. There are however several "informal" *calling conventions* and *name mangling rules* on popular platforms that offer a degree of interoperability.

Comment: @Quentin: Why that? His answer is very well true for any compiled language (and many interpreted, too). The ABI depends not only on the language, but also on the architecture. For ARM, there are actually various, including various PCS (which is the main issue for linking actually). Just alone the fact that C (as much as C++) leaves room for the size of types is an indicator for multiple ABIs.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, alright. Name mangling had me doubt, as well as the fact that C is always regarded as *the* robust interop language. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Quentin: The C language does not specify an ABI, nor name mangling rules, nor calling conventions. It's true that on any one platform there's usually enough documentation about the prevailing ABIs to make interop possible, but it's not part of the standard. If you wanted, you could perfectly well write a C implementation whose linker knows about function return types, say, and can tell you if they're mismatched. It's just that nobody has done this yet.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not sure, but would LTO not provide that inherently? For langauges, other than C/C++, this has been done. E.g. Oberon uses a binary interface format which included type information used by the loader/linker. Not sure about Ada, though.